# Cannot get any output when passing array through preprocessor

Tags: 9

In my preprocessor I assign the following:

```
$variables['myVar'] = "value";
```

And in my twig file I can do the following and I get the value printed:

```
{{ myVar }}
```

If I however assign an array like this in my preprocessor:

```
$variables['myVar'] = ['name' => 'John','surname' => 'Doe'];
```

I am not able to get any output either through the outputting the variable, doing a dump or even trying to run it through a for loop:

```
{{ dump('myVar') }}
{% for items in myVar %}
```

I have cleared cache as well. Any ideas would be welcome :)

Comment: What do you get with {% for key,val in myVar %}{{ key }}: {{ val }}{% endfor %}? Did you "register" myVar with hook_theme or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in THEME.theme

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  $variables['myVar'] = ['name' => 'John','surname' => 'Doe'];
}
```

in page.html.twig

```
name: {{ myVar.name }}
surname: {{ myVar.surname }}
```

or array iteration

```
{% for key,var in myVar %}
{{ key }}: {{ var }}
{% endfor %}
```